# I don't understand this loop

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, stringbuilder

I'm trying to build a card game in java, and I want to get cards to show up with their Suit and number, so a a 4 of diamonds would be 4(diamond), except the (diamond) would be U+2666 unicode.

The example I have in my book to display the suits for the cards is as follows, but I don't really understand it.  I'm used to for loops that use i < 0, i++.  Could somebody help explain it or at the very least compare it to a normal for loop?  Thanks!

Alternatively, could I just use a switch statement to display the suits?

```
private String getCardsDisplay() {
    StringBuilder cards = new StringBuilder();


    for (Card card : hand.getCards()) {
        cards.append(" ");
        cards.append(card.getRank());


        switch (card.getSuit()) {
            case CLUBS:
                cards.append("\u2663");
                break;
            case DIAMONDS:
                cards.append("\u2666");
                break;
            case HEARTS:
                cards.append("\u2665");
                break;
            case SPADES:
                cards.append("\u2660");
                break;
        }
    }
    return cards.toString();
}
```

Comment: Assuming that hand.getCards() return an array (which I will call your hand) then the whole for loop could read : "For each card in your hand, append the rank and suit". It essentially iterates through each element in the array and gives each element as the card object.

Comment: It's called an "enhanced for loop" or a "for-each" loop. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special kind of loop called "for each."  It means that it loops through each object, in order, in the array or list returned by hand.getCards().  For example, if it is an array of cards that reads {"10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"} it will get the Card objects and loop through them in that order.  It's written for convenience to the programmer, and it also makes the code more readable to those who understand "for each."

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [***for-each***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) or [***enhanced for***](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) loop. This loop iterates over the elements of an array/Collection, not over indexes. For example, this `for`:

```
 for (Card card : hand.getCards())
```

will iterate over the array/Collection returned by the method `getCards()`. The type of the elements are specified in `Card card`. You will be able to access each element by the name `card`, so you can call a method from the class `Card` like

```
card.getRank()
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a special "enhanced for loop". In versions of Java before Java 5, that loop would be written as:

```
Card[] cards = hand.getCards();
for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    Card card = cards[i];
    // the rest of the loop
}
```

This is somewhat cumbersome. So, when Java 5 came out, it incorporated a new syntax for looping over an array. That is what you see here.